# facebook SSH key in android app

Tags: android, facebook, sdk

I have *.jks instead of *.keystore I extracted the SSH key from my certificate.jks but when I try integrate facebook in my app for sharing the sharing dialog flashs out and go not letting me to share ,for your attention I am not using debug key because I released my app to the public .

Comment: Can you provide a code snippet?

Comment: in other phone when I click to interacte with facebook share it says your app is still in developement not setup yet ?

Answer (score 0):

I changed settings  "Your app is currently live and available to the public"